# Cardinality and Relationship among tables

Tags: foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, table-relationships, cardinality

There is a table named `Department`, which shows the various departments of a University.
And there is a table named `Branch`, which shows various branches (such as electrical, computer science, mechanical, automobile, law, literature etc.)

Conditions:

1. A `Department` can have any number of `Branch`es.
2. A `Branch` can be associated to single `Department`.

It means the cardinality between `Department` : `Branch` is "one to many".

Now the problem is, in this kind of situation, if I make `dept_id` (an attribute of table: `Department`) as primary key. How would I be able to associate more than one `branch_id` ( an attribute of table : `Branch`), because if I do it so, I may violate the primary key condition of `dept_id` itself.

How to deal with cardinality and making foreign key both go hand in hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a foreign key `dept_id` to `Branch` referencing `Department.dept_id`.

Since `dept_id` is unique in `Department`, each row in `Branch` can thus obviously be linked to exactly one row in `Department`, and there can be multiple rows in `Branch` containing the same `dept_id`.

Thus there will be a one-to-many relationship between the two.

---

To depict a many-to-many relationship, you need to create a third table that contains:

- A foreign key `dept_id` referencing `Department.dept_id` and
- A foreign key `branch_id` referencing `Branch.branch_id`

Comment: Yes. Edited with an explanation. Saying there is a one-to-many relationship between the two and the cardinality between the two is one-to-many means the same.

Comment: Edited answer with how to do that.

Comment: The same as a many-to-one relationship, but make the `dept_id` foreign key unique.